# How can I make a HTML/CSS Slideshow Fill the screen as a background when pictures are different sizes?

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I have tried many ways but keep running into the problem of I have small pictures which I want to cover the page without replicating. The images are in a simple cross fading slideshow made of HTML and CSS. If anyone knows a solution please help. The code is here https://www.codecademy.com/byteSurfer77914/codebits/Lg1o3G/edit

Comment: @DrewJordan The OP has a *specific problem*, which makes it off-topic for CodeReview.

Comment: ah, thanks. I didn't know that was only for general review.

Comment: @DrewJordan It is only for review of *working* code. It's a common mistake people make.

Comment: ok, gotcha. makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
   font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
   font-weight: 300;
 }
 .css-slideshow {
   min-width: 1024px;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
 }
 .css-slideshow figure {
   margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   background: #;
   position: fixed;
 }
 .css-slideshow img {
   box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .css-slideshow figcaption {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   color: #fff;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
   font-size: .8em;
   padding: 8px 12px;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .5s;
 }
 .css-slideshow:hover figure figcaption {
   transition: opacity .5s;
   opacity: 1;
 }
 .css-slideshow-attr {
   max-width: 495px;
   text-align: right;
   font-size: .7em;
   font-style: italic;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .css-slideshow-attr a {
   color: #666;
 }
 .css-slideshow figure {
   opacity: 0;
 }
 figure:nth-child(1) {
   animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(2) {
   animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(3) {
   animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(4) {
   animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(5) {
   animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(6) {
   animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(7) {
   animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
 }
 figure:nth-child(8) {
   animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
 }
 @keyframes xfade {
   0% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   10.5% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   12.5% {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   98% {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="css-slideshow">
    <figure>
      <img scr="https://scontent-atl1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/v/t1.0-9/11696006_552542634884522_6974810122332336734_n.jpg?oh=dc9f855a26758a984d62764398a993b5&oe=561D8818" alt="class-header-css3" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-172" />
      <figcaption></figcaption>

    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://scontent-atl1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t1.0-9/11698916_549988971806555_4844839813799871571_n.jpg?oh=494882d5e67135ad9ca19325272049dd&oe=56197441" alt="class-header-semantics" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-179" />
      <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://scontent-atl1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t1.0-9/11707540_553121584826627_9134683716038424767_n.jpg?oh=d262e8103383780cf894371fbd3660c5&oe=56191F45" alt="class-header-offline" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-178" />
      <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://scontent-atl1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/v/t1.0-9/11692694_552316594907126_8150294442120674585_n.jpg?oh=d1b1c34e04e3d76623a1c71a3740e98f&oe=5612DBBC" alt="hike1" class="hike10" />
      <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://scontent-atl1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t1.0-9/11011897_554257658046353_2992577499490719642_n.jpg?oh=16bf71549ec783130c57c53aac6a0cd6&oe=5622A3BA" alt="hike" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-176" />
      <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://scontent-atl1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/10846061_548303745308411_6417320283077954578_n.jpg?oh=39836d991c85c44e5a07b12425df4781&oe=562742BA" alt="class-header-multimedia" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-175" />
      <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://scontent-atl1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10644879_450777305061056_6728861527484189803_n.jpg?oh=c706542ae39e77541fa279f424cf2303&oe=561CA391" alt="class-header-3d" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-174" />
      <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://scontent-atl1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t1.0-9/10398022_450320015106785_2038216740372010379_n.jpg?oh=7ddda1c9e3f524da0f93100b4cddb4b2&oe=565121A3" alt="class-header-performance" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-173" />
      <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>

</body </html>
```

Try this code

```
.css-slideshow img{
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Although you should not do it as it would stretch images which are smaller.

Comment: I can't tell if it is just codecademy's interpreter or the code but now it cuts off the bottom of the picture

Comment: If you want the image to fill the entire screen, then it would cut the image either in width or height, based on the aspect ratio of the image and the aspect ratio of the screen you open it in.

Comment: If you make the css to be 
`width: 100%;height:100%;` then it would not cut the image, but if would make the image disproportionate and lose its aspect ratio.

Comment: How would I make it not cut off no matter what screen I use?

Comment: So do I need different images to make it not cut of or be disproportionate?

Comment: Well it really depends on the images you use. 
Lets say you have an image whose initial dimensions are like 1000 x 800px. 
Now lets say your screen size is 960x600px. 
For the image to fit the entire width, it would take 960x768px, if scaled according to the initial ratio. That means it would be cropped vertically. 
Same goes if you try and fit the image vertically.